# Use ckeditor for enter Message in ASP.net and LINQ to SQL

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

I want to use Ckeditor for Entering text and I want to save that text in Database,but when I Write the text in editor and I want to save it in database this error appeared .

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (editor1="

this is my code :

```
M.Body = editor1.Value;
```

my feild that I want to save the text is Body and I use LINQ to SQL for relation with database .

How do I can save text in database whit this editor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try encoding your CKEditor HTML output.  Add this to your CKEditor declaration:

```
oCKeditor.Config['HtmlEncodeOutput'] = true;
```

More information about the error you're getting on [ASP.NET Website](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/request-validation/)

Comment: are you using just plain javascript version of the CKEditor or the ASP.NET control (FCKeditor.Net 2.6.3)?

Comment: my friend I can solve this problem with your example in the Link,and thank you

Comment: if you're setting your validation to false (<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>) then it's not exactly the safest way to go; but if that works for you I guess that all that matters